# Remove Object From JSON in Postgress

Tags: postgresql

I have a table called shopping_cart:

```
INSERT INTO shopping_cart(
user_inv_id,
dod_id,
items) VALUES (
2,
263748598, ARRAY ['{"Name":"Boot"}', '{"Name":"Hat"}']::json[]
)
```

Im able to add to the current JSON using:

```
UPDATE shopping_cart
SET items = items || ARRAY ['{"Name":"1"}', '{"Name":"2"}','{"Name":"3"}']::json[]
WHERE dod_id = '263748598';
```

I cant figure out how to delete an object from the array. I would like to delte based on "Name"

Comment: Don't ever use `json[]`. Rather, put a JSON array value in a `json` column

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not best solution, but seems to work. We don't delete items, just create new array without one element

```
update shopping_cart set
items = 
(select array_agg(elem) from  unnest(items) AS a(elem)  
    where elem->>'Name' <> 'Hat'
)
where dod_id = 263748598
```

Comment: Like luck would have it, after I posted I refactored the table to JSONb and created a new call and it worked...

Answer (score 0):

Like luck would have it, after I posted I refactored the table to JSONb and created a new call and it worked...

//Table Creation

```
CREATE TABLE shopping_cart
(
    dod_id varChar PRIMARY KEY,
    user_name varchar(250),
    items jsonb
);
```

//Add to JSON cell within items column

```
UPDATE shopping_cart SET items = items || 
'{"Name": "Sock",
        "Size": "Medium",
        "uuid": “2”}’ ::jsonb
WHERE dod_id = '263748598';
```

//Delete index within JSONb cell

```
UPDATE shopping_cart SET items = items - 
Cast((SELECT position - 1 FROM shopping_cart, jsonb_array_elements(items) with 
      ordinality arr(item_object, position) 
WHERE dod_id='263748598' and item_object->>'uuid' = '2') as int)
WHERE dod_id='263748598';
```